# Cadence genus synthesis script issue

Tags: digital-logic, synthesis, cadence, cad

I have written a genus synthesis script for synthesizing my design of Direct Digital Synthesis for a University project. The DDS design is working properly in simulation and is fully synthesizable. I have also written the SDC constraints for the I/O ports. Currently specified the clock to be 100MHz standard. However, the output reports are not generating properly it seems. I have the main top module "dds.v" and inside I have instantiated 3 sub modules "sine.v", "cosine.v" and "phase_accum.v" and the sub modules also have some sub modules instantiated inside of them for example a simple adder and register. But I cannot see these modules in output area and power reports. Also, even if I change the clock rate to lets say 150 or 200 or some other value, I don't really see a change in the cell count in area report. Not sure what is wrong with the script but here it is:

```
set_db init_lib_search_path ../lib/
set_db init_hdl_search_path ../rtl/
read_libs slow_vdd1v0_basicCells.lib

read_hdl dds.v sine_lut.v cosine_lut.v phase_accum.v phase_truncate.v register.v adder.v

elaborate dds
read_sdc ../constraints/dds.sdc

set_db syn_generic_effort high
set_db syn_map_effort high
set_db syn_opt_effort high

syn_generic
syn_map
syn_opt

#reports
report_timing > reports/report_timing.rpt
report_power -by_hierarchy  > reports/report_power.rpt
report_area   > reports/report_area.rpt
report_qor    > reports/report_qor.rpt

write_hdl > outputs/dds_netlist.v
write_sdc > outputs/dds_sdc.sdc
```

Comment: Not familiar with genus. Check the output net list .v if particular items are really opt away. And search for keywords like 'remove' in run log.

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thanks.